# Is there away to force HttpWebRequest post data to be sent right away?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Using Wireshark, Send **POST** data with **HttpWebRequest**, the data is being sent in a secondary packet instead of being applied to the primary packet and then sending secondary packets if need be.

**HttpWebRequest** is sending only header information in the first packet and then **POST** data in the second packet.  This is causing the HTTP Server to respond before the full HTTP request is received.  Server is acting like an empty **POST** message even with the Content-Length being set in the header because no content has been append to the initial HTTP request packet.

This issue is only replicable using **.Net HttpWebRequest**. Using python, curl, or every other form of HTTP Client request does not cause this issue.

Currently using .Net framework 4.5.

Any way to force **.Net HttpWebRequest** to send POST data in the initial request packet?

P.S. I am not talking about the TCP SYN and ACK packets that come before Application content.

Comment: You are aware that the server is broken, right? And it can't be fixed?

Comment: Agree ^. What server is doing this?

Comment: You don't think it might be a good idea to mention the fact that the server is fundamentally broken and that you're trying to find a workaround for it in the question?

Comment: Did in the second paragraph.  I know the workaround, is there away to make it work in .Net without having to marshal in a 3rd party solution like libcurl.  And the content being sent can easily fit in a single packet exit whom ever implemented HttpWebRequest decided two is always needed.

Comment: @Mike - did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue with the header data and post data being sent in two separate packets.